# ActionView::Template::Error (variable @fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix is undefined)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I get an error while trying to load any page:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (variable @fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix is undefined)
(in /app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Program</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__242882506_70513990'   app/controllers/problems_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

What I did before? Just run `bundle update`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because of bootstrap update I will need to update bootstrap's assets:

```
rails g bootstrap:install -f
```

There are a new line in assets:

```
+@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix");
```

Comment: You saved my day. Just an add-on... Using -f will force overrides so may be good to mention to backup anything you added to the file generated by previous bootstrap:install (in my case it erased some changes I made to `app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less`).

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me. This is because, When you update your Bootrap gem, You should update Its js and less css. Do

```
rails g bootstrap:install -f
```

This will add a line to your app/assets/css/bootstrap_overrides.css.less file
like

```
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix");
```