# variable @fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix is undefined

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm working on my first project with bootstrap and I get this error whenever I try and view my project. I've looked around and haven't been able to find someone with same problem. Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

---

**Less::ParseError in Search#index**

```
Showing /Users/Basil/Dropbox/College/CS 50/playedby.me/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #4 raised:

variable @fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix is undefined
  (in /Users/Basil/Dropbox/College/CS 50/playedby.me/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)
Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <!DOCTYPE html>
2: <html>
3: <head>
4:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application.css', :media => "all" %>
5:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
6:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
7: </head>
```

---

**Here is my bootrstrap_and_overrides.css.less**

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
body { 
padding-top: 60px;
}

@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";

// Set the correct sprite paths
@iconSpritePath: asset-path('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png');
@iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-path('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png');

// Set the Font Awesome (Font Awesome is default. You can disable by commenting below lines)
// Note: If you use asset_path() here, your compiled boostrap_and_overrides.css will not 
//       have the proper paths. So for now we use the absolute path.
@fontAwesomeEotPath: '/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot';
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: '/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff';
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: '/assets/fontawesome-webfont.ttf';
@fontAwesomeSvgPath: '/assets/fontawesome-webfont.svg';

// Font Awesome
@import "fontawesome";

// Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
//
// Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
// you may use and inherit here
//
// If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
// See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html for their names and documentation
//
// Example:
// @linkColor: #ff0000;

@successBackground: white;
@successText: @green;
@errorBackground: white;
@errorText: @red;

@navbarHeight: 60px;

.alert-success, .alert-error {
    border: 10px solid @green;
    padding: 2%;
    font-size: 125%;
    line-height: 150%;
}

.alert-success { 
    border-color: @green;
}

.alert-error {
    border-color: @red;
}
```

Comment: Note that `@fontAwesomeEotPath is undefined` is indeed this same issue

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701132/

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Notice that your bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less doesn't have the variable the error is complaining about.

Add the following line with the other @fontAwesome variables and you should be good.

```
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix");
```

Or update your twitter bootstrap install by running `rails g bootstrap:install -f`.

Comment: you just saved my afternoon.

Comment: It was not clear to me that I had to re-run the generator either on an upgrade. TY

Answer (score 20):

This has also happened to me. When you update the Bootstrap gem you must then update its javascript and css. To do so, run this:

```
rails g bootstrap:install -f
```

This will add a line to your app/assets/css/bootstrap_overrides.css.less file which looks like:

```
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix");
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: note that this will remove all custom changes from `app/assets/css/bootstrap_overrides.css.less`

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke: Thats correct. But usually we dont use this file to add our custom methods.Anyway thanks for pointing out that.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you forget to install bootstrap, you can try command below.

```
rails g bootstrap:install
```