# Rails Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Rails app getting the following error:

```
Less::ParseError in Home#index

Showing /Users/burtondav/sites/requestsys/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #20 raised:

Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined
  (in /Users/burtondav/sites/requestsys/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)
Extracted source (around line #20):

17:       }
18:   </style>
19: 
20:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

Some GEMS I'm using:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'less-rails'
  gem 'commonjs'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

end
```

It seems to be a problem with LESS that Bootstrap uses.

I've read several other similar issues.  So, I upgraded Ruby to 1.9.3p374.  But, that didn't fix the problem.

Any ideas?

THANKS!

UPDATE

This is the bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";

// Set the correct sprite paths
@iconSpritePath: asset-path("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings");
@iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-path("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white");
```

Comment: Can you update with the content of bootstrap_and_overrides? Have you tried adding your gem to the assets pipeline? Also, I needed to add gem 'less-rails' both in and outside of the assets group because of this bug: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/437#issuecomment-10110777

Comment: I tried adding 'less-rails' inside and outside the asset group.  I get the same error.  If I remove the 'bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less' file and add the 'bootstrap.css' file, the app runs fine (except I lose my bootstrap css changes).

Comment: Can you update with the content of bootstrap_and_overrides?

Comment: Looks like this would help: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/72

Comment: I tried removing everything from 'bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less' except for the first 2 lines -  that do the import.

Comment: I read that one and updated Ruby to 1.9.3

Comment: I think I also read running the rails g bootstrap:install command

Comment: The last thing I did was run the rails g bootstrap:install command

Comment: If I run gem list - I see these: less (2.2.2, 2.0.9)
less-rails (2.2.6, 2.1.6).  Could the less (2.2.2, 2.0.9) be the problem?  But, I don't have less in my gem file. Does less-rails install it?

Comment: I don't think so, according to this comment: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/72#issuecomment-3820092

Comment: This is what I get when I run $ ruby -v : ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]

Comment: Maybe I will have to do this: use static bootstrap stylesheets, without less - But, I don't really want to.

Comment: Are you using less with your other stylesheets? I'm using the less version of bootstrap because it's more native to the original version but I use SASS otherwise. Try this one then: https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Well, I'm going to get rid of less.  I might use sass or go native css.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I'll sum up our convo here in an answer

Comment: I'm having the same issue and am trying to figure it out. I don't want to switch to SASS and don't want to use the compiled css because I take advantage of the mixins for my own less files. I should add that this is new as of Bootstrap 2.3. Prior to upgrading last night everything was working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following up with you in the comments. It seems the answer lies in opening a github issue with either twitter-bootstrap-rails or less-rails describing your issue. You could also follow on the original issue: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/72

Otherwise two solutions are offered to you:

1. Use the SASS version: https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap
2. Use the native css version available on their site: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Answer (score 4):

I have temporary fixed the issue. There is a syntax change to the mixins.less that seems to only be supported by LESS.js

As an example:

Post-2.3 release:

```
.offsetX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
  .offset@{index} { .offset(@index); }
  .offset@{index}:first-child { .offsetFirstChild(@index); }
  .offsetX(@index - 1);
}
```

Pre-2.3 release

```
.offsetX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
  (~'.offset@{index}') { .offset(@index); }
  (~'.offset@{index}:first-child') { .offsetFirstChild(@index); }
  .offsetX(@index - 1);
}
```

After adding (~"") back in everywhere it was removed (you will have to view a diff from 2.3 and the release before to see where its been removed, all my assets compile again with no errors and still using LESS.

This change was only in mixins.less btw and only about a total of 5 or 6 lines.

Comment: This solved the issue for me as well.  I'd still love to know why these lines bug out on 2.3???

Answer (score 3):

Got the same failure. Fixed it by rolling back twitter-bootstrap-rails to version `2.1.4` (as of this writing the latest is `2.2.4`)

```
# Gemfile
...

group :assets do
  ...

  gem "therubyracer"
  gem "less-rails"
end

gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", '2.1.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in sort of a roundabout way, so YMMV. In my case this error was caused by updating twitter-bootstrap-rails from 2.1.6 to 2.2.5, without any edits to any files. So trying to reproduce this in development, I noticed 404s for requests to halfling icons:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings"):
```

Since I'm using font-awesome, I simply removed all references to those sprites from my CSS:

```
# bootstrap_and_override.less
//@iconSpritePath: asset-path("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings");
//@iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-path("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white");
// Glyphicons
//@import "twitter/bootstrap/sprites.less";
```

That in turn led to this error:

```
variable @fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix is undefined
```

which is is a common upgrading issue and [solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708303/variable-fontawesomeeotpath-iefix-is-undefined) by adding this line:

```
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix");
```

After that, everything is working again.