# word.charAt is not a function, Datatable error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

I have integrated datatable in my Rails app (4.2.4) like this:

application.js

```
//= require datatables.js
//= require ../metronic/assets/global/plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js
//= require ../metronic/assets/global/plugins/datatables/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js
```

An example of use is the index page:

```
<table id="students" class="datatable  table table-striped table-hover table-datatable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="left">Nome</th>
                        <th class="left">Cognome</th>
                        <th class="left">Classe</th>
                        <th class="left">Codice Fiscale</th>
                        <th class="left">Indirizzo</th>
                        <th class="left">Email</th>
                        <th class="left">Cellulare</th>

                        <th/>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <% @students.each do |student| %>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left"><%= student.nome %></td>
                        <td class="left"><%= student.cognome %></td>
                        <td class="left"><%= student.sigla_classe%></td>
                        <td class="left"><%= student.codice_fiscale %></td>
                        <td class="left"><%= student.indirizzo %></td>
                        <td class="left"><%= student.email %></td>
                        <td class="left"><%= student.cell %></td>
                        <td class="right">
                            <%= link_to 'Vedi', student %>
                            |
                            <%= link_to 'Modifica', edit_student_path(id: student) %>
                            |
                            <%= link_to 'Elimina', student, style:'color:#F00;', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Sei sicuro?' } %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <% end %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

This is the controller:

```
def index
        @students = Student.all
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.pdf do
                pdf = StudentPdf.new(@students, view_context)
                send_data pdf.render,
                          filename: 'Elenco Studenti',
                          type: 'application/pdf',
                          disposition: 'inline'
            end
        end
      end
```

If I do a search, the error disappears, I just can not figure out what I did wrong, I do not think it was wrong in the index are almost sure that the error lies in the way in which I integrated datatables.

For the rest everything works, the table is well displayed with correct pagination.

Comment: can you show your index controller action code.

Comment: @DMH certainly, I've just added.

Comment: Hmm cant see any issues with the index action. Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675066/rails-cannot-call-method-charat-of-undefined

Comment: @DMH Thanks but I don't think   it is my case, because  `return word.charAt(0) === '"' ?` 
is in datatable.js , I don't have  any problem with bootstrap...

Comment: I have this same problem.

Comment: @christopherclark i didn't found  any solution jet

Comment: @PatrickBarattin I removed all other jquery references, and made sure the latest jquery library was loaded first, then loaded all others that depended on jquery like the datatables library.

Comment: @christopherclark this is a grate solution thank you!