# 'fontawesome.less' wasn't found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have an application thdirat uses Twitter Bootstrap for styling. It has worked fantastically for a year. Suddenly I get this error in development:

```
ActionView::Template::Error ('fontawesome.less' wasn't found
  (in /Users/me/myapp/code/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)):
```

What could be causing this? I haven't changed the Gemfile or anything.

The line causing the error is the stylesheet inclusion tag in my template:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

Comment: rails g bootstrap:install -f

source: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708303/variable-fontawesomeeotpath-iefix-is-undefined

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` I changed:

```
// Font Awesome
@import "fontawesome;
```

to:

```
// Font Awesome
@import "fontawesome/font-awesome";
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

when I run [rails-select2-example](https://github.com/jseifer/rails-select2-example), I met the same error. According to the [font-awesome.less' wasn't found. #593](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/593), I changed:

```
@fontAwesomeEotPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.2");
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.2");
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.2");
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.2");

// Font Awesome
@import "fontawesome";
```

into:

```
@fontAwesomeEotPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix");
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.woff");
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
@fontAwesomeSvgPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular");
// Font Awesome
@import "fontawesome/font-awesome";
```

It worked fine!

Answer (score -1):

In application.css

> *= require font-awesome